# Why can't I launch notepad++ from the command line anymore?

Tags: django, editor

I'm teaching myself some Django tonight using the local dev package at instantdjango.com

I made it through half the tutorial, building a basic map with points on it, then closed out of the console for a bit.  I just fired it back up and now when I try to use notepad++ to edit files, console tells me it doesn't recognize the command.  What happened?

When I as working through the first half, I was able to type: "notepad++ filename.ext" and I'd get a text editor that would pop up.

Now when I type that, it doesn't recognize the command.

How do I get back the ability to use the text editor and how did I lose it?

Comment: not programming related. Ask in superuser.com

Comment: ah! also, using "start" before "notepad++ filename.ext" might be needed. ex. "start notepad++ filename.ext"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the directory in which the Notepad++ executable resides is not in your system's PATH.  For information about fixing this please see [How to set the path in Windows 2000 / Windows XP.](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: Does this explain why it was working the first time I started the Django dev environment but not the second?

Comment: Is it possible to add a batch file wrapper in an another directory that resides within the %PATH% in order to keep the %PATH% as small as possible?

Answer (score 32):

In a windows terminal, you can launch notepad++ with the following:

```
start notepad++ <filename>
```

Note that the filename is optional.

Comment: works with git bash as well, just confirmed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `gitbash` or `cygwin`, you can create an alias

```
alias np='start notepad++'
```

And use

```
np myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done, in this way you dont have to type `notepad++`
Create `np.bat` file with this set of commands

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %*
```

place `np.bat` file in `c:\Windows`

open the command prompt and type `np` or `np myfile.txt` and enter.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a change to this registry key:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Notepad++.exe]`

You can download a zipped .reg file from [Donn Felker](http://www.donnfelker.com/running-notepad-from-the-command-line/) that lets you open a file with just an `n` shortcut.

I edited the .reg before running it and to make sure the path to Notepad++ is correct (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)`) and I also changed the shortcut to `n` instead of `n`.

Then double click to add to your registry.